# Java Phones: How to set up JTAPI?

Tags: java

I want to use JTAPI (1.4 - latest) to create an app that will call my phone whenever I need it to. I downloaded JSR043 (JTAPI specification) and have been reading the API docs and it seems pretty straight forward with respect to *how to code JTAPI*.

However I seriously doubt that getting a Java app on my laptop to call my cell phone doesn't require some 3rd party or middle man service provider and possibly other entities/configurations as well.

So I ask: besides using the JTAPI in my Java code, what do I need to install or set up to have a Java app that calls my phone? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I remember correctly, all you'll need is your JTAPI app (that does the work) and a SIP account.

Answer (score 2):

Hardware with phone capabilities and a phone service ( a service from an ISP ).

Also you have to consider that:

> There are no Reference Implementations (RI) or Compatibility Tests
>   Suites (CTS) available for the Java Telephony API.

http://java.sun.com/products/jtapi/overview.html

Comment: Thanks @user827992 (+1) - I'm a dunce when it comes to telephony, can you be more specific about what hardware I would need and clarify if my ISP (TimeWarner) would provide such a service? Also, by "no RI", does that mean there are *no* implementations of JTAPI?

Comment: By "*hardware with phone capabilities*" are you talking about some kind of Asterisk server or something?

Comment: a modem with a SIM card in it, a modem connected to a local phone line that you can use, a way of having a phone connection, you can also use the Jtapi with a large PBX or something like that, you need a phone connection, in a way or another, the software stack is always in Java, the Jtapi are supposed to handle this on their own.